# Get max length dataframe from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

ex :

```
df1
id A B C
1  2 2 2
2  3 3 3

df2
id A B C
1  5 5 5
2  6 6 6
3  8 8 8
4  0 0 0

df3 
id A B C
1  6 6 6

len(df1) is 2
len(df2) is 4
len(df3) is 1
```

Here the maximum length dataframe is df2,
So How to find maximum length dataframe from multiple dataframes
I want to build logic(function), it should return the biggest df from the same
Thank you

Comment: Thanks Guy, but it will return the length of df, it should return the biggest df

Comment: What do you mean biggest df, in which terms? currently your example show based on the number of row.

Comment: @KarnKumar biggest df which means the df which have maximum rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max` with `len` as key

```
df = max(df1, df2, df3, key=len)
```